# How are counters in Cassandra stored on the disk?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am unable to understand how Cassandra counters are stored on the disk.

**Create test table**

```
create table testcounter (
id text,
count counter,
PRIMARY KEY(id))
WITH compaction = {'class': 
'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 
'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 
'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
```

**Add data**

```
update testcounter set count = count + 10 where id = 'testrow';
```

**Check sstable**

```
nodetool flush test testcounter 
sstabledump /usr/local/var/lib/cassandra/data/test/testcounter-87d6ae20908e11e9a5779f988085883a/mc-1-big-Data.db
```

**Response from sstabledump**

```
[
  {
    "partition" : {
      "key" : [ "testrow" ],
      "position" : 0
    },
    "rows" : [
      {
        "type" : "row",
        "position" : 63,
        "cells" : [
          { "name" : "count", "value" : 422215477737628, "tstamp" : "2019-06-16T23:30:34.423470Z" }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

**Update existing data**

```
update testcounter set count = count + 10 where id = 'testrow';
update testcounter set count = count + 10 where id = 'testrow';
```

**Flush**

```
nodetool flush test testcounter
```

At this point, there are two sets of db files.

```
ls /usr/local/var/lib/cassandra/data/test/testcounter-87d6ae20908e11e9a5779f988085883a/
backups             mc-1-big-Digest.crc32       mc-1-big-Statistics.db      mc-2-big-CompressionInfo.db mc-2-big-Filter.db      mc-2-big-Summary.db
mc-1-big-CompressionInfo.db mc-1-big-Filter.db      mc-1-big-Summary.db     mc-2-big-Data.db        mc-2-big-Index.db       mc-2-big-TOC.txt
mc-1-big-Data.db        mc-1-big-Index.db       mc-1-big-TOC.txt        mc-2-big-Digest.crc32       mc-2-big-Statistics.db
```

**sstabledump for mc-1**

```
[
  {
    "partition" : {
      "key" : [ "testrow" ],
      "position" : 0
    },
    "rows" : [
      {
        "type" : "row",
        "position" : 63,
        "cells" : [
          { "name" : "count", "value" : 422215477737628, "tstamp" : "2019-06-16T23:30:34.423470Z" }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

**sstabledump for mc-2**

```
[
  {
    "partition" : {
      "key" : [ "testrow" ],
      "position" : 0
    },
    "rows" : [
      {
        "type" : "row",
        "position" : 65,
        "cells" : [
          { "name" : "count", "value" : 422215477737628, "tstamp" : "2019-06-16T23:34:37.245893Z" }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

It looks like there are no tombstones and even the counter values are not stored. What is happening behind-the-scenes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 2.1 its actually a read before write then stores essentially a packed tuple which isnt very obvious or easy to deserialize. Might be worth opening a jira to have sstabledump deserialize the context and make it more readable.

For more details see: https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/whats-new-in-cassandra-2-1-a-better-implementation-of-counters

Comment: Wow I had no idea! So, are you saying that sstabledump is currently not even able to deserialise sstables with counters?

Comment: it does, it just prints it out the combined data as a long though instead of extracting the timestamp value and id which is really what you would want to see.

Comment: I see. Are tombstones never created for counters?

Comment: there are no tombstones for counters